# SMS Verification using Firebase and React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, sms-verification

I wanna do sms verification through firebase in react native
i am using react-native-firebase library to access firebase SDK
although i have tried their builtin method for sending verification code but it didn't work
Method i used:

```
    firebase.auth().verifyPhoneNumber('+p #')
               .on('state_changed', (phoneAuthSnapshot) => {
           console.log(phoneAuthSnapshot)
       })
    firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber('+p #')
   .then((confirmResult) => {
       console.log(confirmResult)
   })
   .catch((error)=>{
       console.log("catch"+error)
   })
```

I have tried a lot of methods. I am on Firebase free plan and have uploaded the SHA1 Hash correctly as well.

Error I am getting

> code: null
>
> error: null
>
> state: "sent"
>
> verificationId: "AM5PThB_qcB3PDSoEsEGy2fKu4kAqg-SOcrF45oz5Zx5gi8Rv3JJM94hstJJvT9XoWM2O9oqlHybMVHMt-ajH9PK-mEy2YFIMiEjEdOIkI622WxnJ3PGPvX6wNz_0UpUBk54D0OfDn9T"

but the code is not being sent to my Pakistani or US number.

Comment: Shouldn't you be on the  paid plan for phone auth to work?

Comment: @Lelo There is a free quota too. See https://firebase.google.com/pricing